# Material color Attributes are transparent

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I want to use the `?attr/colorPrimary` attribute on the background of a LinearLayout but it is everytime transparent. I define all my colors and themes in the default values folder. I support API 8 to 21 and use AppCompat-21. It works only if set the color via code. Has anybody an idea?

**EDIT:**

*themes.xml*

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Blue</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/card_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_yellow_200</item>
</style>
```

*layout.xml*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

        <de.wackernagel.playball.views.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetStart="56dp"
            app:indicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:selectedColor="?attr/colorAccent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

*manifest.xml*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".PlayBallApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RulesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RuleDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
            android:parentActivityName=".RulesActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".RulesActivity" />
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is an update about my problem.

- I see NO color by using: `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"`
- I see NO color by using: `android:background="@color/dukes_blue_dark"`
- I see a color by using: `view.setBackgroundColor(
  getResources().getColor( R.color.dukes_blue_dark ) );`

**EDIT 3:**

OK now i know more and found a hacky way to colorize my views.
I think my theme isn't applied in the right way to my third Activity (Main->Rules->RuleDetails).
So i copy my hole theme, rename it and apply it only to my RuleDetailsActivity. Now it works. I tried also to give the new theme to my application but then it isn't applied again.

So My solution looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_yellow_200</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PlayBallTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dukes_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_yellow_200</item>
    </style>

</resources>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.wackernagel.playball"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.4" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".PlayBallApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_play_ball"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ...

    <activity
        android:name=".RuleDetailsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/PlayBallTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".RulesActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Do you override you style.xml?

Comment: I extend my style from Theme.AppTheme.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: could you post app theme? and way how to use it

Comment: please post your manifest as well - my suspicion is related to 2 styles - `AppTheme` and `MyAppTheme` which both extend base theme. I suspect you are using the first one (the one w/o attributes)

Comment: The second is used for overlays and the first for norma inbuild actionbar style without toolbar.

Comment: I remove the second theme and make only one of both. But the problem still exist.

Comment: Edit 3 show a running solution but it's only a workaround.